# How to move my camera in OpenGL

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm trying to have my camera move in the way games do in first person. I have shapes drawn and oriented to look like a hallway, so I need the camera to move forward as if your moving through the hallway. What lines of code should I use, and where should I put them?

Answer (score 1):

You should see the things from the opposite side, you don't move the camera. Instead you move the world so that its projection changes according to the camera (which doesn't really exist) position.

This is usually done by having a projection matrix which embeds the current camera position and orientation and this matrix is used inside your shaders, after having applied the model matrix (remember it's not symmetric).

Take a look a [this](http://tomdalling.com/blog/modern-opengl/04-cameras-vectors-and-input/) good tutorial to get the necessary knowledge. Basically everything reduces to:

```
 gl_Position = camera * model * vec4(vertex, 1);
```

Comment: My code is based off the android tutorial, where I have     gl_Position =uMVPMatrix*vPosition   What is the relationship between my variables and the variables you posted?

Comment: Your matrix is already a composition of the model, the view and the projection matrix. So it already contains the camera information inside.

Comment: What about the vec4(vertex,1). Is that an added component to help the camera "move" or do I already have that implemented as well?

Comment: That is the vector representing the position of the vertex, it's required in any vertex shader since gl_Position is a function of the original position multiplied by the various matrices.